# Calling Method faster then Retrieving Something From Memory

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So this is my question: **Why would calling a method be faster then retrieving something from memory?**

Noticed when an id attribute is specified on a DOM element, user agents automatically attach the element's reference on their global scope.

Since user agents already reference all elements, which have their id attribute specified, why would I need to use document.getElementById("")?

Within an application, I would:

```
//Retrieving the value, I could possibly write this two way.
<script>
var fromGlobalScope = myElement.value;
var documentGetById = document.getElementById("myElement").value;
</script>


<input id="myElement" value="someValue" />
```

Doing some research, it is supported by all major browser, but their may some browser that do not support, which will break.

However, I could simply write:

```
<script>

//See if the element is on the global scope.
var fromGlobalScope = myElement ||document.getElementById("myElement");

</script>
```

I believe patterned correctly, I can automatically have references to all elements that have an id attribute. I don't have to call document.getElementById();

Using an resident property and I wouldn't have to walk the DOM, would think there would be a good performance benefit.

I created a jsPerf to see the benefit: [enter link description here](http://jsperf.com/dom-to-reference)

My surprise was using document.getElementById() was a lot faster?

So this is my question: **Why would calling a method be faster then retrieving something from memory?**

Using document.getElementById, I would be calling a method that may or may not walk the DOM. At least, I will be calling an address for the value.

With a property on the global scope that should be quickly available as it is placed in some memory location.

I have include jsPerf results below:
[image]

I created another jsPerf with another thought:
[explicitly setting a property on the window object](http://jsperf.com/memeory-vs-method)

However, I still believe learning why can help with the mechanics that are at play, which may result in something helpful.

Comment: ["As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector()."](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)

Comment: I wouldn't use the direct access, I've always used the method. But your question is legit and I'm curious, too, how this is possible. Most probably the direct access is not what it seems. There are properties that are getters unbeknownst to developers. With Harmony (ES6) those special cases will be easier to identify. I guess this is one of those cases. Still... it's unexplainable for me :D

Comment: Thank you, mostly I thought a nice performance gain would be had utilizing something already present. I believe testing if global value is present and then falling back to getElementById if absent would solve code being brittle.

Comment: @humble.rumble: Perhaps others upvoted this question for the same reason I did: it is a well written, researched and thought-provoking question. In the best scientific tradition, deDogs proposed a hypothesis about the relative performance of different DOM access methods, immediately falsified it, and now wonders "why?" Of course you are right that browser developers optimize for the proper DOM methods and those are what we should use, but it's still an interesting question - and not exactly a duplicate of those others since it's about the *performance* of these methods.

Comment: @humble.rumble I understand, thank you. If browsers optimize for getElementById then what about retrieving a in memory property? Something that is already on the window context? I believe no optimization is needed. A question.

Comment: @humble.rumble - I think your test is broken. it's window.test, not document.test. See http://jsperf.com/direct-reference-vs-proper-method/2

Comment: @humble.rumble: you are correct, so I find it very interesting that you are correct. Look at your jsPerf test, it was interesting that document.test was a lot faster than window.test? I know you don't care, but it sparks a why in my reasoning.

Comment: document.test is fast because document.test returns undefined, so nothing happens.

Comment: My **guess** would be that *getElementById* is using a highly optimised lookup of only those elements that have an id (there's only one in the document), whereas the global variable version must lookup over all global variables and even if they're optimised with an index too, it's a much bigger list to look through. Try increasing the number of ID'd elements (add 1,000 or so with similar IDs) and see if the gap closes.

Answer (score 1):

From [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)

> ### 5.2.4 Named access on the Window object
>
> The Window interface supports named properties. The supported property
>   names at any moment consist of the following, in tree order, ignoring
>   later duplicates:
>
> - the browsing context name of any child browsing context of the active document whose name is not the empty string,
> - the value of the name content attribute for all a, applet, area, embed, form, frameset, img, and object elements in the active document that have a non-empty name content attribute, and
> - the value of the id content attribute of any HTML element in the active document with a non-empty id content attribute.

So the browser will probably walk the DOM tree to resolve a named property. In contrast `getElementById()` just needs to look the id up in (say) a hash map.

While the browser could maintain a hash map of the first matching element to that algorithm, maintaining that map would impose a performance penalty that would rarely pay for itself. In contrast the browser is looking up elements by their id constantly, so it pays to keep the id map.

Comment: I doubt very much that a browser would "walk the DOM" to find global references given that it almost certainly indexes all elements with a name or ID while parsing markup and inserting DOM nodes to optimise performance for *getElementById* and *selectors*, particularly CSS.

Comment: @RobG - Yes maybe. I wouldn't stake money on it. But it's not clear otherwise why lookup by id alone is so much faster. Any explanation based on "only one element for a given id" is a non-starter, because invalid HTML can contain multiple elements with the same id, and CSS will match all such elements, so browser's id indexes probably have to include all the matches,

Comment: Since IDs are supposed to be unique, browsers can ignore multiple identical IDs if they want and can return the first, last or any particular one. That issue will be sorted during parsing of the HTML or as the DOM is modified if that happens later. The [*Selectors API*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#findelements) infers that where there are multiple elements with the same ID, it should return the first. But that isn't stated explicitly.

Comment: @RobG - Whatever the API says, that's not what CSS implementations do. To change that now would be impossible, too many existing web pages would break. It all other cases, the browser never has a free choice. The HTML5 spec requires that the first element in DOM order with the given id is used.

Comment: Browsers have always treated the spec more as helpful hints than strict rules, which is probably why the HTML5 spec is as much about what browsers *actually* do as what the spec authors would *like* them to do. So strict compliance is seen as a bug if other browsers do something in a non–compliant way. Note [*DOM 3 getElementById*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId): "*If more than one element has an ID attribute with that value, what is returned is undefined.*". ;-)

Comment: Compared to the [*whatwg "DOM living standard*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyidelementid): "*The getElementById(elementId) method must return the first element, in tree order, within context object’s descendants, whose ID is elementId, and null if there is no such element otherwise*" and noting that most browsers don't implement *getElementById* as part of the *Element* interface (thought of course they have it for the *document* interface).